# How to manipulate the DOM inside of map function using onChange event on one of the checkboxes with react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So first I import really simple "database" object from a different file which has a students array property in it. After that I map through the students array to display all of the students on the window object. All went well until I tried to dynamically change class name on one of the div tags inside of map function every time when state for status is changing to true I want to display information otherwise that div should stay invisible. After implementing the code below and trying to tick the box I am getting error "Cannot create property '0' on boolean 'true'". Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank You for Your interest in that case.

```js
import React,{ useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import db from './db'
import './App.css'

const App = () => {
 const [status,setStatus] = useState(database.map((student) => {
   return student.isChecked
 }))
 return db.students.map(({name,id,email,isChecked}, index) => {
    return (
      <form key={id} className='form'>
        <h2>
          {name}
        </h2>
        <select name='student_attendance' className='form__dropdown' defaultValue='present'>
          <option value='present'>
            present
          </option>
          <option value='absent'>absent</option>
        </select>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor={id}>Left early</label>
          <input type='checkbox' name='leftEarly' id={id} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor={email}>Arrival late</label>
          <input type='checkbox' name='arrivalLate' id={email} onChange=                 {(event) => {
              setStatus(status =>
                status[index] = event.currentTarget.checked
                )
            }}/>
        </div>
         <div className={status[index] ? 'visible' : 'invisible'>
           <p>time: </p>
         </div>
      </form>
    )
  })
}

export default App
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I dont think `status` is doing what you think it is. When using `useState`, the value you provide in parenthesis will be the initial value. Inside your `useState` you are mapping over each item in the list and returning whether or not that student `isChecked`.... however what this will do is simply set `status` to be the value of `isChecked` on the first student. 

Remove the `status` state value, and try replacing all uses of `status[index]` with `isChecked`.

Comment: @RyanSaffer The value of `database.map((student) => {
   return student.isChecked
 })` is an array of (presumably) boolean values, so the initial value of `status` will be an array. Seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to `setStatus` should be either:

- The new value for `status`

or

- A function that takes a previous version of `status` and returns the new version

You are passing it a function that *modifies* the received value of status, and then returns a boolean value. So it appears that `status` is changing to that boolean value, and then the `status[index]` in your `className` expression is essentially evaluating `true[0]`, which results in the error.

To fix this, fix your use of the `setStatus()` function:

```
setStatus(status => [
    ...status.slice(0, index),     
    event.currentTarget.checked,
    ...status.slice(index + 1)
])
```

You may also want to try this, which doesn't rely on the `event` properties:

```
setStatus(status => [
    ...status.slice(0, index),     
    !status[index],
    ...status.slice(index + 1)
])
```

Or even this:

```
setStatus(status => 
    status.map((x, i) => (i === index) ? !x : x)
)
```

Comment: I try Your code and yes actually that solved the current problem, but after implementing it I got another error in the console saying "Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the method `currentTarget` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is a no-op function. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist()." Also all of the values in the status array are changing to undefined after firing the checkbox event

Comment: The other issue from my previous comment also solved by just saving event.currentTarget in a variable and then calling in with .checked. Thank You so much for help!

Comment: @MarcinRygielski Ok, you might be better using the `onClick` event instead of `onChange`, and basing the change on the previous status instead of the event properties. See my edit above.

Comment: This seems like more clear solution tbh. Thank You for extending Your previous solution it is really helpful to see different approaches.

Comment: To get rid of the synthetic event is reused error you can do: `const checked = event.currentTarget.checked;
setStatus(status => [
  ...status.slice(0, index),     
  checked,
  ...status.slice(index + 1)
])`